# Label Background Showing With ExtJs and Geoext

Tags: extjs, openlayers

I found this patch. [Label Background patch](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2349) Openlayers and it was working on  vectore_feture_text.html sample.

When I try a in html "label background  sample" is  working and shows background rectangle ,

but not displayed in ext js and geoext mappanel.

I saw it had been rendered in another project mappanel. But do not get a solution.

Can you help me to find proper solutions?